# Cohomology of $BU(n)$

Tags: homology-cohomology, formal-power-series, classifying-spaces

The cohomology ring for $BB\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$, where $x$ lies in degree $2$. My question is about $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$. I was trying to find a topological group (ideally an internal group in CW-complexes) such that the cohomology ring of $BG$ is $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, ..., x_n]]$, where $x_1, \dots, x_n$ lie in some degrees (but I was aiming for degree $2$).

$BU(n)$ classifies $n$-dimensional vector bundles, which suggests to me that the cohomology ring of $BU(n)$ could resemble $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$, or also $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]^{S_n}$.

Where can I find an account of the cohomology ring of $BU(n)$ (if the above suggestion is true), or if that's not the case, then how might I obtain a cohomology ring of $\mathbb{Z}[[x_1, \dots, x_n]]$?

Comment: The cohomology ring for $BB\mathbb{Z}$ is $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ not $\mathbb{Z}[[x]]$. Are you using a different convention which would lead you to believe it is the latter?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese wait, are you sure? Nlab says it's R[[x]] ...https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complex+projective+space#:~:text=Finally%2C%20the%20cohomology%20ring%20of,%5B%20%5B%20c%201%20%5D%20%5D%20.

Comment: Π$_{i}$ ℤ makes more sense than $\oplus_{i}$ ℤ, just from an initial point of view.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese do you know anything about how B relates to products? and perhaps something about U(n) classifying n-dimensional vector bundles, like a source for that?

Comment: As I suspected, you and I are using different conventions (see Remark 4.4 on the nLab page you linked to). Using your convention for the cohomology ring, we have $H^*(BU(n); \mathbb{Z}) = \prod_{i=0}^{\infty}H^i(BU(n); \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n]]$ where $\deg c_i = 2i$.

Comment: Oooooh! That's amazing! Thanks so much. Do you know a link? @MichaelAlbanese

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese perhaps you also know about the cohomology ring of unitary operators on Hilbert space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, when $X$ has infinitely many non-zero cohomology groups, there are two non-equivalent definitions for the cohomology ring of $X$: the direct sum or the direct product of all the cohomology groups. You are using the latter (many other sources use the former, so make sure to check conventions).

Since $S^1 = U(1)$ is a model for $B\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is a model for $BS^1 = BU(1)$, we see that $\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}$ is a model for $BB\mathbb{Z}$. With your convention, it follows that $H^*(BB\mathbb{Z}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[x_1]]$ where $x_1$ has degree $2$. In $H^*(BU(1); \mathbb{Z}_2)$, the generator $x_1$ can be identified with the first Chern class $c_1$.

It follows from the Kunneth Theorem, and the fact that $H^*(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty}
; \mathbb{Z})$ is torsion-free, that $H^*((\mathbb{CP}^{\infty})^n; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]]$ where $\deg x_i = 2$. Since $BG_1\times BG_2 = B(G_1\times G_2)$, we see that $(\mathbb{CP}^{\infty})^n$ is a model for $(BU(1))^n = B(U(1)^n) = B((S^1)^n) = BT^n$.

The inclusion $T^n \to U(n)$ of a maximal torus induces a map $BT^n \to BU(n)$, and the induced map on cohomology is injective (this is effectively the splitting principle). One can then show that $H^*(BU(n); \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}[[x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n]]^{S_n} \cong \mathbb{Z}[[c_1, c_2, \dots, c_n]]$ where $\deg c_i = 2i$, see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/413550/21564) for example.

In the comments you asked about the cohomology ring of the space of unitary operators on a Hilbert space. If the Hilbert space is infinite-dimensional, then the space of unitary operators is contractible (with the norm topology or the strong operator topology), see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/298302/models-for-eilenberg-maclane-space-kz-3#comment742154_298302), so the cohomology is trivial. In the finite-dimensional case, the space of unitary operators is $U(n)$ and $H^*(U(n); \mathbb{Z}) \cong \Lambda_{\mathbb{Z}}[x_1, x_3, \dots, x_{2n-1}]$ where $\deg x_i = i$, see Corollary 4D.3 of Hatcher's [*Algberaic Topology*](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ehatcher/AT/AT.pdf).